# "Specified cast is not valid" only on release build from MS build

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, msbuild, il

I am getting a "Specified cast is not valid" valid when doing only a release build from MSBuild 4.0.  I tested this out in using a release build from Visual Studio 2012 and didn't get this issue.  I also tested this out using a debug build from MSBuild 4.0 and didn't get this issue.

Exception: [image]

Code

```
    public abstract class CachedSessionBase : ISessionObject
{
    protected Dictionary<MethodBase, Object> _getAndSetCache = new Dictionary<MethodBase, object>();

    protected TResult SetAndGet<TResult>(ObjectFactory factory, Func<TResult> func)
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        var methodBase = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod();

        if (!_getAndSetCache.ContainsKey(methodBase))
        {
            _getAndSetCache[methodBase] = func.Invoke();
        }

        return (TResult)_getAndSetCache[methodBase];
    }
```

The error is being thrown on this line

```
return (TResult)_getAndSetCache[methodBase];
```

Comment: I would add some tracing lines to double check that whatever comes out of `_getAndSetCache[methodBase]` is actually of type `TResult`. In release configuration (with optimization turned on), the stack frame may change if methods are inlined. `stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()` <-- that sort of code shouldn't really go into production. There is an attribute you can apply to members to stop inlining, but I cannot remember what it is... saw it used in CSLA.NET of old.

Comment: Just to clarify, I reckon the issue is that `stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod()` is returning something different in release than it is in debug. I would advise not using it, but can't offer any alternatives.

Comment: can you log the type of the object before returning it?

Comment: StackTrace should never be used in production code. The only rare exceptions is error handling/logging that attempts to do more intelligent analysis of what occurred (even then i'd question the validity of what is being done)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is likely that the call stack is different than what you are expecting it to be. Your method may be getting inlined, then `GetFrame(1)` is retrieving the caller's caller. When the value is retrieved from the dictionary, it is of a different type because it is for a different method.

You could try adding the attribute `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining]` to `SetAndGet` to prevent the inlining optimization for the method.

Comment: +1 spot on. It's the code optimiser in release config that is causing this for sure.

Comment: Tried this answer.  Though on correct track and very close, will not work in my scenario.  I was using stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod(), to know who the caller is.  The caller function was getting optimized inline.  The caller will need to implement  [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining].  There is no way to force the caller to do this, so I will have to look at another solution.

Comment: @Anish You really should. Using `StackTrace` for something that is not debugging is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Thank you.  I will try a different pattern.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when running `nuget pack` which invoked

> MSBuild auto-detection: using msbuild version '15.0'...

but the problem was solved by running `dotnet pack` which invoked

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.3.409.57025 for .NET Core

Comment: For all using .net core on mac this is the correct answer. Thanks a ton stephen